# RegSetValueEx silently fails to write to HKLM

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry

I'm trying to write in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` from my C++ application like this:

```
HKEY key;
if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"), NULL, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &key) == ERROR_SUCCESS){
    if (RegSetValueEx(key, TEXT("lcr"), 0, REG_SZ, (const BYTE*)runcmd.c_str(), (runcmd.size()+1)*sizeof(wchar_t)) != ERROR_SUCCESS){
        cout << "ERROR" ;
    }else{
        cout << "OK" << endl;
    }
    RegCloseKey(key);
}else{
    cout << "ERROR" ;
}
```

But it silently fails and nothing happens!
I tried both running as normal user & running as administrator.
What is the problem?

Comment: Capture the return codes and examine them.

Comment: @AlexK. : I am! no error code! HKCU woks but HKLM fails silently

Comment: By "silently fails" you mean existence of error code you did not include in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your application is subject to UAC [registry virtualization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965884.aspx). Because you did not include a manifest in your application, the system drops into an XP (!) compatibility mode. When you write to restricted parts of the registry under HKLM, the system re-directs them to what is known as the virtual store under HKCU.

You should add a manifest to your application so that you are no longer virtualized. If you really do need to write to HKLM then you will need to specify the `requireAdministrator` option in the manifest so that your application is executed with elevated rights.

Probably your next move is to take some time to read the documentation that I linked to above and be sure that you fully understand all the implications of UAC.

Comment: Except that [per the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965884.aspx): "*Registry virtualization is disabled for the following:... Keys and subkeys of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes`, **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows`**, and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT`.*" So it shouldn't matter if the app is manifested or not (it should be in general, though) due to the *particular* key that is in question.