# RegOpenKeyEx fails on HKLM even tho requireAdministrator is enabled

Tags: windows, winapi, registry, startup

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31265939/regsetvalueex-silently-fails-to-write-to-hklm) saying that in order to access Windows Registry keys you need to have `requireAdministrator` execution level in your manifest file.  Something about Registry virtualization.

I am working with Visual Studio 2017, and in the project settings (Linker - Manifest file) I changed the execution level to `requireAdministrator` (and VS17 asks me to run it with admin rights to debug the program), but it still doesn't work.

**EDIT**: All registry functions return with no errors (claiming everything is fine).  Here is a snippet:

```
void AddStartupKey(char* path)
{
    HKEY hKey;
    LPCTSTR sk = TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run");

    RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sk, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey);

    LPCTSTR value = TEXT("Test");

    RegSetValueEx(hKey, value, 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)path, strlen(path));

    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
```

`path` equals to `argv[0]` (exe path).

My question is, why no value is added to the key even though all functions are successful?

**EDIT**: Here is a screenshot of the manifest settings in VS17:

[image: Visual Studio 2017 Manifest File Settings]

Comment: When you say it "fails", clarify what you mean - does it give an exception, or does it just not find the thing you asked for, in which case maybe what you asked for isn't there. Think about giving us a snippet of your code so we might have more of a clue what you are doing.

Comment: @Richardissimo Changed made, I'm new to the community I'm sorry for my mistakes

Comment: *"Execution level"* and *"registry virtualization"* are unrelated. But since you never explained, what you expect, or how you verified that your expectations weren't met, it is impossible to answer the question. Incidentally, what question are you asking? Please read [ask].

Comment: You shouldn't have registry virtuatlization problems if your execution level is requireAdministrator according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965884.aspx) @IInspectable

Comment: You don't need to use `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` when `KEY_SET_VALUE` will suffice. Do not request more rights than you actually need. Also, your `path` is an ANSI string, so this code will only hope to work correctly if your project is not compiled for Unicode so `RegSetValueEx()` maps to `RegSetValueExA()` and not `RegSetValueExW()`. Since you are dealing with ANSI anyway, you should just use `RegSetValueExA()` directly and not deal with `TCHAR` at all.

Comment: Oh, right. There *is* registry virtualization with respect to access rights. However, there is also registry virtualization when running 32-bit code on a 64-bit OS. You are most likely running into an issue with bitness. You need to tell us the bitness of your OS (probably 64-bit), the bitness of the process, making the registry access, and the bitness of the tool you are using to verify the changes.

Comment: @Remy: That's true, but it is likely unrelated to the issue at hand. Might want to add to your comment, that this may be unrelated. Although I don't know what to make of the contradiction between the question title and question body.

Comment: @IInspectable: Registry Virtualization does not apply in this situation, whether the app is 32bit or otherwise, because 1) the presense of a `requestedExecutionLevel` manifest disables virtualization, and 2) keys under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows` are not virtualized to begin with. [This is documented behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965884.aspx).

Comment: @RemyLebeau The code doesn't compile to Unicode, Thanks for the advice about using SetValueA directly. Noted about KEY_SET_VALUE.
I also tried to do it with no path (empty data only value) but it still doesn't create anything.

Comment: @IInspectable Like Remy said I suppose it is not related but anyways:
My process is 32bit based, OS is 64bit and tool is regedit (supposely 64 bit)

Comment: @NivM.: "*and tool is regedit (supposely 64 bit)*" - you can use Task Manager to know for sure whether the 32bit or 64bit version is running.  You might also consider using [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see exactly what Registry keys your app is *really* trying to access, which access rights are being requested, and what error codes are being returned.

Comment: @Remy: That document seems to imply, that registry virtualization is enabled for 32-bit processes (running on a 64-bit OS), regardless of the `requestedExecutionLevel`. Or am I misreading the documentation?

Comment: @IInspectable: you are misreading the documentation. If `requestedExecutionLevel` were ignored for a 32bit process and Registry virtualization were always enabled simply because of bitness alone, then a 32bit process could never avoid Registry virtualization at all, and that is simply not true. The presence of `requestedExecutionLevel` (regardless of its value) does disable Registry virtualization in a 32bit process

Comment: @Remy: To be expected. Thanks

Comment: @RemyLebeau Indeed regedit is running as 64 bit and not 32, as you can see in the photo the execution level is Administrator (I've also tried running the exe file directly (not through vs17) but it still doesn't seem to work)
Any clues ?

Comment: your app is 32 or 64 bit ? you add to probably to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`. use `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` if want add to native node

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the program you provided, it showed me that the process is trying to access:
"HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"

Comment: @RbMm Indeed 32 bit, What do you mean by KEY_WOW64_64KEY ?

Comment: strange question. are you read documentation ? look in regedit - your value under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` - want `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` ? use `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` when call `RegOpenKeyEx`

Comment: [Accessing an Alternate Registry View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @NivM. You are running a 32-bit app that is trying to access a 64-bit Registry key, so it is encountering [Registry Redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232.aspx). See [32-bit and 64-bit Application Data in the Registry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072.aspx) and [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384253.aspx). `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` is a special flag that a 32-bit process can pass to `Reg(Open|Create)KeyEx()` to access a 64-bit Registry key.

Comment: @NivM. No problem, don't take the criticism personally. Your reputation gives away that you're new to the forum; but be assured that you are welcome, and I hope you can see that if you work a bit harder on asking a good question, there are *lots* of people here who can help. I posted my comment, you improved your question and look at all the help you got since then! I definitely recommend reading the 'How to Ask' and MCVE articles referred to by other commenters before your next question (MCVE is [MCVE]).

Comment: You don't know whether or not there are errors. Your code ignores all error codes.

Comment: UAC virtualization (i.e. redirection to "HKCU\Software\Classes\VirtualStore" and "%LocalAppData%\VirtualStore") typically applies when a legacy 32-bit application (not execution-level aware) is run without administrator access and then writes to and subsequently reads from a select set of system keys and directories. WOW64 redirection (i.e. redirection to "HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node" and "%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64") is the system view for 32-bit applications running on 64-bit Windows. 32-bit applications that are WOW64-aware can use the `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` flag and "SysNative" directory.

Comment: @RemyLebeau works perfectly, Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with adding `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` to `RegOpenKeyEx()`. Thanks everyone.